# get id and count mysql record in same table for seperate list

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This is my mysql query. i need to get id and count value when i passed in comma seperated id

```
SELECT tag_id AS id, COUNT( tag_id ) AS count FROM tag WHERE tag_id IN ( 1, 2, 3, 28 );
```

I get

```
---------------
| id  | count |
---------------
|  1  |  4    |
---------------
```

Expected result is:

```
----------------
|  id  | count |
----------------
|  1   |  2    |
|  2   |  1    |
|  3   |  5    |
| 28   |  0    |
----------------
```

Pls help....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using aggregate function you should group them

```
SELECT tag_id AS id, COUNT( tag_id ) AS count 
FROM tag WHERE tag_id IN ( 1, 2, 3, 28 )
GROUP BY tag_id ;
```

[**GROUP BY (Aggregate) Functions**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)

Answer (score 1):

You need a `group by` statement:

```
SELECT tag_id AS id, COUNT( tag_id ) AS count
FROM tag
WHERE tag_id IN ( 1, 2, 3, 28 )
GROUP BY tag_id;
```

Your query is an aggregation query without a `group by`, so it returns one row (treats all rows as a group).

Next, if you want to return counts of 0, then the query needs to be structured differently.  Here is a version using `left join`:

```
select ids.id, count(t.tag_id) as cnt
from (select 1 as id union all
      select 2 union all
      select 3 union all
      select 28
     ) ids left join
     tag t
     on t.tag_id = ids.id
group by ids.id;
```

Comment: You beat me by some seconds :(